# Retrieving images, chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with basic chrome extension. My goal is to retrieve img elements from webpage.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "My first chrome extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": { "scripts": ["script.js", "jquery-1.8.3.js"] },
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "name": "Do something with images",
        "icons": ["icon.png"]
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

script.js:

```
var imgs = [];

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

//  imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    imgs = $('img');
    if(imgs.length > 0){
        alert("abc");
    }    
});
```

On pages with images alert is not displayed. imgs.length is 0. Whereas in javascript console on the same page when I type:

```
imgs = $('img');
imgs.length;
```

I get 29 images. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onClicked` handler doesn't run on the page; instead, it runs within an separate extension environment. Instead, you need to inject a script into th etab:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "img_script.js"
    });
});
```

where `img_script.js` is a script file in your extension.

Or, if you must, do:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: "imgs = $('img'); if(imgs.length > 0){alert('abc');}"
    });
});
```

However, this is *horrible* for readability and future code maintenance. *Please* don't ever do this.

If the script only acts on the page (e.g., you're just replacing the `src` property of all of the images on the page with a new value), you're done. If you need the extension to do further processing on the results (e.g., you want to count how many images are on the page and then call `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText` with that number), have the injected script [pass a message](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) back to the extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However it still doesn't work. Even this doesn't:
`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            code: "alert('abc');";
        }
    }`

Comment: Do you have the `tabs` permission in your manifest? Also, my code had a syntax error in it; I missed a closing parenthesis for `executeScript` (which is now corrected).

Comment: my permissions: `"permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ],`

I noticed syntax error, This does not work: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
         code: "alert('abc');";
     });});`

This does: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 alert('aaa');
     });`

Comment: Sorry, there's yet another syntax error -- there shouldn't be a semicolon after `code: "alert('abc');"`